# Is it possible to use a local project instead of a nuget dependency with DNX?

Tags: nuget, dnx

Let's say that have 2 DNX projects (A and B). Both of these projects are stored in separate repositories and are published as nuget packages.

Project A depends on project B. Under normal circumstances Project A would just pull project B's nuget package.

There is an instance where I'd like to work on both Project A and project B at the same time. I'd like to be able to be able to make changes to project B and use those changes in project A without having to build a package deploy it and then pull it.

I know that in the Ruby world, it's possible to do this with bundler. You can tell it to use a local directory instead of a dependency. I have also heard that it's also possible to do something similar with bower.

Is such a thing possible with DNX. If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify additional folders to search for using the `projects` property in `global.json`.

something like...

```
{
    "sources": ["src","tests","../relative/path/to/other/project/src/dir/"]
}
```

will then have DNX load those projects from source, instead of trying to load them as a nuget package.

Comment: [doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json#projects)